# Как передать в запрос параметр?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Всем привет, есть вот такой код

```
private const string SELECT_PARTNERS_PARAM = "SELECT_PARTNERS_PARAM.sql";
// Метод для вызова запроса
private static string GetQuerySelect(string sql_file)
        {
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream($"Rtb.Api.Dal.Query.{sql_file}"))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
public async Task<IEnumerable<RtbModel>> GetPartnerDal(int[] ids)
        {
            var listOfPartners = new List<RtbModel>();
             // Тут идет обращение к запросу
            var sqlCommand = GetQuerySelect(SELECT_PARTNERS_PARAM);
            var cmd = CreateCommand(sqlCommand);

            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                   // Остальной код работы
                }
            }
            return listOfPartners;
        }
```

Собстевнно говоря сам SQL-запрос

```
SELECT
    [AdvertXrefDsp].[advertId],
    [Dsp].[dspId],
    [Dsp].[name],
    [Dsp].[endpoint],
    [Dsp].[protocol],
    [Dsp].[protocolOptions]

FROM 
    [AdvertXrefDsp]

INNER JOIN [Dsp] on [AdvertXrefDsp].[dspId] = [Dsp].[dspId]

WHERE
    [advertId] in (@advert_ids)
```

Вопрос, как можно передать параметр **@advert_ids** в SQL запрос из кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрим два способа.

Первый способ не нуждается в создании нового типа в БД. Но его не стоит использовать, если нужно передать очень много (тысячи) параметров.
Второй способ позволяет передавать любое количество данных в `IN`, но необходимо создать табличный тип.

---

1. Ваш запрос должен выглядеть так: `SELECT ... WHERE [advertId] IN ({0})`. На место `{0}` мы подставим параметры.

```
// ids - коллекция айдишников
var parameters = string.Join(", ", ids.Select((_, i) => "@p" + i));

string sql = GetQuerySelect ...;
sql = string.Format(sql, parameters);


using (var conection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    await conection.OpenAsync();

    using (var cmd = conection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        // Тут задаём значения параметрам
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
        {
            // Укажите правильный тип SqlDbType
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p" + i, SqlDbType.Int).Value = ids[i];
        }

        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

2. Используем Table-Valued Parameters.

Для этого в БД нужно создать тип:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.AdvertIds AS TABLE
(
    Id INT    
);
```

Запрос SQL при этом должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT ... WHERE [advertId] IN (SELECT Id FROM @advert_ids)
```

Теперь используем его.

```
// ids - коллекция айдишников

var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int)); // укажите правильный тип
foreach (var id in ids)
    table.Rows.Add(id);

string sql = GetQuerySelect ...;

using (var conection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    await conection.OpenAsync();

    using (var cmd = conection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        
        var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@advert_ids", SqlDbType.Structured);
        param.TypeName = "AdvertIds"; // указываем наш тип
        param.Value = table;

        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Освобождайте ресурсы! Для этого оберните их вызовы в `using` или явно вызывайте метод `Dispose`. При этом не важно, создаёте команду прямо здесь или получаете из другого метода.

Answer (score 0):

Кусочек кода
как вариант

```
   int advert_ids = 10;
   Console.WriteLine($"... WHERE [advertId] in ({advert_ids})");
```

Вариант 2

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine($"....WHERE [advertId] in ({getparamarray()})");
    }

    public string getparamarray()
    {
        ..... //делаем что нужно
        return "1 and 2 and 3 and 4";
    }
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, а можно как нибудь передать не одно значение а неколько (скажем массив) в запрос?
При этом желательно не использовать цикл а передать весь массив разом

Comment: SQL запрос это обычная строка. Формируйте строку как хотите любыми методами функциями обработки строк.   Главное получить строку на выходе. Все зависит от вашей фантазии и знания обработки строк. можете вместо {advert_ids} подставить метод функция которая вернет строку из массива. Нет проблем.. Ниже пример кода

Comment: А возможно ли сделать это через тбаличную переменную, на стороне SQL-Server(а)?

Comment: Есть вот такая инструкция (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/table-valued-parameters?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7) и там в пункте "Передача возвращающего табличное значение параметра в параметризованную инструкцию SQL" кокраз как-то передается табличная перменная в параметр